# unable to read some specific values from a USB serial terminal

Tags: c, integration, esp32

I've recently been trying to set up a connection between a game code that I'm writing controller that I made (using an ESP32 and some other interfacing bits). The way I'm currently establishing communication between the ESP32 and the game code is by having the ESP32 first send a uint16_t to serial, then I have the game code read the serial and check the input. Due to some API restrictions on the ESP32, the uint16_t appears to need to be send as a buffer of 2 uint8_t, and then it can be written to serial by writing twice with the right endianness. This was working fine, and I had been able to receive multiple signals from my "receive" function, which quite literally simply reads whatever is on the serial and returns it. But recently I realized that the following signals won't show up if I try to read them:

- 0x04
- 0x0A
- 0x0D
- 0x15

I'm really confused as to why these signals don't get properly read by the "reveive"  function, since I thought I was reading raw unisgned integer values, not characters. But here we are. The following code is what my receive function looks like:

```
__uint16_t recv(int controller){

  // if there's no response, just return FN_RET_NULL
    char *port = malloc(13);
    char *port_use = port;
    __uint8_t msb;
    __uint8_t lsb;
    __uint16_t output = -1;
    switch(controller)
    {
        case 0:
        case 1: 
        port_use = "/dev/ttyACM0";
        break;
        case 2: 
        port_use = "/dev/ttyACM1";
        break;
        case 3:
        port_use = "/dev/ttyACM2";
        break;
        case 4:
        port_use = "/dev/ttyACM3";
        break;
        default: port_use = "err";
    }
    if(port_use == "err")
    {
        printf("[RECV] Wrong Controller Input\n");
        free(port);
        return 0x4;
    }

    int serial_port = open(port_use, O_RDWR);
    // printf("%d\n", serial_port);
    if(serial_port < 0)
    {
        printf("[RECV] Error opening serial port. \n");
    }

    struct termios tty;
    memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));

    if(tcgetattr(serial_port,&tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("[RECV] Error getting serial port attributes 3\n");
    }
    cfsetospeed(&tty,B1152000);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, B1152000);

    tty.c_cflag != (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag != CS8;

    if (tcsetattr(serial_port,TCSANOW,&tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("[RECV] Error setting serial port attributes \n");
        free(port);
        return 0x4; 
    }
    char readbuff[256];
    memset(&readbuff, '\0',sizeof(readbuff));
    printf("[RECV] waiting... \n");

    int num_bytes = 0;
    while(num_bytes < 2)
    {
        num_bytes = read(serial_port, &readbuff, sizeof(readbuff));
        printf("numbytes = %d\n", num_bytes);

        if(num_bytes > 0)
        {
            printf("Some of the readbuf: %x %x %x %x %x %x (0-5)\n", readbuff[0], readbuff[1], readbuff[2], readbuff[3], readbuff[4], readbuff[5]);
        // printf("Recieved [%s]\n", readbuff);
        msb = (__uint16_t)readbuff[0]; // set MSB
        printf("msb: %x\n", msb);
        lsb = (__uint16_t)readbuff[1]; // set LSB
        printf("lsb: %x\n", lsb);
        memset(&readbuff, '\0', sizeof(readbuff)); // DELETE BUFFER
    }
}

free(port);
output = (msb << 8) + lsb; // set output
return output;
```

}

I didn't code all of this, as I am working with other people on this project, so I don't entirely understand everything that's going on, but I don't see anywhere that it could potentially break trying to read these specific characters... at first it made sense to me that the function would have trouble reading the integers corresponding to the EOT character, the Carriage Return, and the New Line character, but I checked and it doesn't fail with any other characters from 0x01 to 0x0F, including the New Form feed character, so I'm not entirely sure why it's these 4 integers that fail to be read properly while. I'm also not sure why NAK would simply get ignored while ACK doesn't.

Is there any way to simply take in the raw integer values from the serial terminal or am I going to have to make sure none of the signals I send contain bytes that are these characters?

Just in case, here is the code  that sends a signal from the ESP:

```
void send_signal(int itf, uint16_t message){
    uint8_t mess_as_list[2];
    mess_as_list[0] = (uint8_t)(message >> 8); // MSB of 'message'
    mess_as_list[1] = (uint8_t)(message & 0xFF); // LSB of 'message'
    tinyusb_cdcacm_write_queue(itf, mess_as_list, sizeof(mess_as_list)); // write to queue
    tinyusb_cdcacm_flush_queue(itf, 0); //flush queue
}
```

Comment: Aside  allocation serves no purpose with `char *port = malloc(13);`.  Might as well `char *port = NULL;`

Comment: `if(num_bytes > 0)  {   printf("Some of the readbuf: %x %x %x %x %x %x (0-5)\n", readbuff[0], readbuff[1], readbuff[2], readbuff[3], readbuff[4], readbuff[5]); ...` should only print the bytes it received, which might be less than 6.  Consider printing the length and then _up to_ 6 bytes.

Comment: As to the 0x04 0x0A 0x0D 0x15, certainly a configuration one in `tty`.  Sorry it has been to long since I ventured down that rabbit-hole.  Search for setup examples in _binary_ mode or at least a _simple_ text mode.